# Dealing with phone numbers in python with a space in the middle

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have the following piece of code, however something odd is happening. When I encounter phone numbers with a space in the middle, the phone number turns into a 0.
For Example: 07777 777777 will turn to 0.

```
import pandas as pd


 df['Phone_Number'] = df['Phone_Number'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]=+', '')
    df['Phone_Number'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Phone_Number'], errors="coerce").fillna(0).astype('int64').to_frame()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the solution provided by @user1740577
as there is no need to use apply-function. Just use pandas str.replace() like this:

```
df['Phone_Number'] = df['Phone_Number'].str.replace(' ', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas [to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas-to-numeric) set invalid parsing as NaN when using the coerce parameter. `fillna` then replace NaN values with 0.

In your situation, a space in the phone number will cause the parsing to fail and return NaN, which is then replaced with a 0.

I don't think you can use regexp with [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). You could directly pass the substring or the characters you want to filter out:

```
"07777 777777".replace(' ', '')
```

or if you do need to use regex:

```
import re
re.sub(r'\s+','',"07777 777777")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected because you can't convert a string with space in the middle to integer directly. However, you can do the following:

This is my dataframe

```
>>> df
     name        toy       born            aa
1  Batman  Batmobile 1940-04-25  07777 777777
```

Now using apply function:

```
>>> df["aa"] = df.apply(lambda row: int(row["aa"].replace(" ", "")), axis=1)
>>> df
     name        toy       born          aa
1  Batman  Batmobile 1940-04-25  7777777777
>>>
```

As you can see, you can get your phone numbers converted into integers. Also, if you want explicitly `int64` then:

```
df["aa"] = df.apply(lambda row: np.int64(row["aa"].replace(" ", "")), axis=1)
```